# How can I redirect stdout and stderr with variant?

Tags: bash, shell, redirect

Normally, we use

```
sh script.sh 1>t.log 2>t.err
```

to redirect log.

How can I use variant to log:

```
string="1>t.log 2>t.err"
sh script.sh $string
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I have 10 cmd lines to print log file, and they'd better have each own's special log file name. So I write a function to generate, and assign to $string. But when running "sh script.sh $string", no log file generate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use 'eval' shell builtin for this purpose. As per man page of `bash` command:

> ```
>    eval [arg ...]
>           The  args are read and concatenated together into a single command.  This command is then read and exe‐
>           cuted by the shell, and its exit status is returned as the value of eval.  If there  are  no  args,  or
>           only null arguments, eval returns 0.
> ```

Run your command like below:

```
eval sh script.sh $string
```

However, do you really need to run `script.sh` through `sh` command? If you instead put `sh` interpreter line (using `#!/bin/sh` as the first line in your shell script) in your script itself and give it execute permission, that would let you access return code of `ls` command. Below is an example of using `sh` and not using `sh`. Notice the difference in exit codes.

Note: I had only one file `try.sh` in my current directory. So `ls` command was bound to exit with return code 2.

```
$ ls try1.sh try1.sh.backup 1>out.txt 2>err.txt
$ echo $?
2

$ eval sh ls try1.sh try1.sh.backup 1>out.txt 2>err.txt
$ echo $?
127
```

In the second case, the exit code is of `sh` shell. In first case, the exit code is of `ls` command. You need to make cautious choice depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out one way but it's ugly:

```
echo script.sh $string | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just put the name into a string variable
and then use data redirection

```
file_name="file1"

outfile="$file_name"".log"
errorfile="$file_name"".err"

sh script.sh 1> $outfile 2> $errorfile
```